# Initialize an array with a loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm coming to Ruby from Java and not really comfortable with it on the second day. What I'm doing is to initialize decks of cards with a given number of decks. Say I will be playing with 2 decks of cards, 52 cards in each deck, and thus 104 cards in total (Jokers are not used). My program goes:

```
def initialize(num)
    @num_of_decks = num
    # initialize my cards here...
end
```

After initialization, I want my cards to be:

```
cards = {"Diamond A", "Diamond 2", ... "Diamond K", 
         "Club A", ...
         ...
         "Spade A", ... "Spade K", // end of the first deck
         "Diamond A", ...
         ...
         "Spade A", ... "Spade K" // end of the second deck
        }
```

I want my program to be able to adapt to whatever `num_of_decks` is. I don't really have a clear feeling of how Ruby loops work by now, especially when it seems that `for` loops are discouraged in Ruby. Hopefully anyone can provide an example here so that I can study how it works.

Comment: You're mixing up your syntaxes, that's not valid Ruby. Arrays use `[]`, hashes use `{}`.

Comment: If you're coming from a Java background, you should be able to think your way through this. It's relatively straight-forward coding problem. The steps you'd take would be identical, though the syntax will be different and the results might not be as idiomatic as they could be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
faces = %w( A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K )
suits = %w( Diamond Club Heart Spade )
deck = suits.product(faces).map { |p| p.join ' ' }

def initialize(num)
  @num_of_decks = num
  cards = deck * num
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but perhaps something like this will work?

```
class DrawPile
  CARD_SUITS = ["Diamond", "Heart", "Spade", "Club"]
  CARD_FACES = ["A", *(2..10).map(&:to_s), "J", "Q", "K"]
  A_DECK = CARD_SUITS.product(CARD_FACES).map{|x| x.join " "}
  def initialize(num)
    @num_of_decks = num
    @cards = (A_DECK * num).shuffle
  end

  attr_reader :num_of_decks, :cards
end
```

Usage:

```
pile = DrawPile.new(2)
pile.num_of_decks #=> 2
pile.cards #=> ["Spade 2", "Spade K", "Heart 4", "Heart 7", ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
a = ['Spade', 'Diamond', 'Club', 'Heart']
b = ['A', *('2'..'10'), 'J', 'Q', 'K']
cards = a.product(b).collect { |a| a.join(' ') }
total_cards = [*(cards * num_of_decks)]
# => ["Spade A", "Spade 2", "Spade 3", "Spade 4", ..., "Diamond A", "Diamond 2", "Diamond 3", ..., "Spade A", "Spade 2", "Spade 3", "Spade 4", ...]
```

And [here](http://ideone.com/zp83kr) is where you can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
suits = ['spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts']
values = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', 'Jack', 'Queen']
cards = suits.product(values).map{|suit, value| "#{value} of #{suit}"}

p cards #=> ["Ace of spades", "2 of spades", "3 of spades", "4 of spades", "Jack of spades"
```